# jsf - pass request param to bean in action method not working

Tags: jsf, action, param

I have a GET parameter `url.xhtml?key=test` which is displayed correctly on my site using:

```
value="#{param.key}"
```

Now i want to pass that param as an argument in an action method call to my bean inside a commandButton?

But it is always empty in the bean?

```
action="#{bean.action(param.key)}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That EL expression is evaluated during the request of processing the form submit, not during the request of displaying the form. The request parameter is apparently not been retained in the subsequent request.

You can do that by adding it as a `<f:param>` to the command component:

```
<f:param name="key" value="#{param.key}" />
```

Comment: This works, but then I have to use `FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get('key')`. Is the use of `<f:param>` then not obsolete? I could look directly into the request map?

Comment: I'm not sure why you "have" to use it and how that's obsolete... Just pass it as action method argument as in your initial attempt `action="#{bean.action(param.key)}"
`? At least, you need to understand that displaying the form and submitting the form are two entirely distinct HTTP requests and that the `param.key` argument in the `action` attribute is only evaluated during the request of submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Helped me to understand the process.